20*4 LCD display correctly using PIC16F628A and not display correctly using PIC18F4550
I am working with PIC18F4550 MCU using Mikro c PRO. Recently I have tried to display information on LCD using PIC18f4550. Simulation on Proteus worked correctly, but when build the circuit in hardware, I get display error. The first character eliminated.

Then I tried to install same code with same circuit with PIC16F268A MCU, the code working correctly,

Here the code of PIC16F268A MIKRO C PRO:
    // LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RB3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
// End LCD module connections

void main(){
trisa.rb0=0;
porta.rb0=0;

  CM0_BIT = 1;
  CM1_BIT = 1;
  CM2_BIT = 1;
  
  Lcd_Init();                        // Initialize LCD

  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);               // Clear display
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);          // Cursor off
  
  Lcd_Out(1,1,"mikroElektronika");                 // Write text in first row

  Lcd_Out(2,1,"EasyPIC6");                 // Write text in second row

  Lcd_Out(3,1,"Lcd4bit");                 // Write text in first row
  Lcd_Out(4,1,"example");                 // Write text in second row
  
  while(1){
   porta.rb0=~porta.rb0;
   delay_ms(1000);
  }

  }

The code of PIC18F4550 is:
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RB3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
// End LCD module connections


void main() {

  ADCON1=15;
  
  Trisa.ra0=0;
  porta.rb0=0;
  
  Lcd_Init();                        // Initialize LCD
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);               // Clear display
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);          // Cursor off
  
  Lcd_Out(1,1,"mikroElektronika");                 // Write text in first row
  Lcd_Out(2,1,"EasyPIC6");                 // Write text in second row
  Lcd_Out(3,1,"Lcd4bit");
  Lcd_Out(4,1,"example");

  while(1) {
  porta.rb0=~porta.rb0;
  delay_ms(1000);
  }
}

The Oscillator configuration shown in following Image:

The lcd library documentation in the link:
Lcd documentation library in Mikro c pro ide
The MCU for library used is HD44780D HITACHI, but I use LCD with MCU of SPlc780D. Will that affect the display?
Can you help me with this?

Please link the data sheet/source of the display.

What help you need with it? You are using a commercial compiler product which comes with their libraries and there is no source code available to investigate. If they don't work then you can ask their support. It could be a bug in the library that can't work with your hardware, maybe PIC is too fast or slow or along those lines, so delays between commands are not correct.

The help I need is Displaying problem for this issues.why the library bug happened with pic18 and not pic16.? Since the lcd MCU I used is SPL not hitachi and the library used for hitachi


add delays and see if that helps. 2) scope signals and look for clues.


I have tried to add delays, when I display character it works , when I display words or more, the problem appeared.

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to extend and clarify. -- This cannot be the complete source code, as it is cannot be compiled. Please extend it to a minimal, complete and reproducible version. Please add the source code of the LCD functions. Or if these are part of a supplied library, please add a link to its documentation.

The MCU for library used is HD44780D HITACHI , but I use lcd with MCU of SPlc780D , is that affect on display ?, I have edited the post with library doccumentation and more information about lcd.

Sounds like a timing error. Please provide oscillograms.

I use Crystal Osillator (8MHZ) and two capacitors of 22pf.What you mean of oscillograms?

How can I test the Crystal osillator?

How does the library know what speed the chip is running at? Is this speed accurate? This sure looks like a timing issue.

The library is built in for the IDE (MIKRO C PRO FOR PIC) and I don't know How the speed to be set.

Another word for oscilloscope capture. A logic analyzer would do the job too in this case.

How can I put the crystal in the test circuit, is there a certain schematic?

I have installed MPLAB XC8 compiler and test the lcd with another external library, the lcd worked perfectly. I suppose that the built in library in mikro c doesn't match with 2004A lcd and pic18f4550 since it has worked perfectly on pic16f28A and Arduino. I got this after 2 monthes trying interface with pic18f4550
